# nativescript-contacts How to sync with google contacts?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, google-contacts-api

Using Nativescript 5.0 with Angular

Using nativescript-contacts plugin to read, modify and create contact. Its working perfectly.

Contacts created by my Android App using nativescript-contacts are not getting sync with Google Contacts.

Andorid phone shows the newly created contact (name & number), so there is no problem in contact creation process, but I expect this newly created contact should get sync in with google contacts. I am checking google contacts on web using the same gmail account as it is used in Android phone.

I just want newly created contact to be backed up, so in future this phone breaks down, I will get all those contacts created by my App from google contacts.

I am using exactly same code as shown in this page of the plugin. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-contacts

Any pointers for me, to get it done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contacts plug-in saves the contact on the first available account on device, fortunately if that becomes your Google account then sync will be taken care by default.

In case if that is not a Google account then you will have to override the [save method to choose right account](https://github.com/firescript/nativescript-contacts/blob/master/contact-model.android.js#L262).

Comment: Manoj, stackoverflow should include lots of emojis to express gratitude towards people like you. Thanks a ton again.

What should I study to become expert like you? My background is way back from classic ASP 3.0 (year 2000), VC++, MFC, XML, ColdFusion (Year 2000 again) and plenty of embedded programming & designing.

Comment: Thank you for the gratitude, but honestly I'm no expert. But if you ask me for suggestion, I have just one rule for myself - Learn any technology / language but from the basics. Often I see most people would skip basics and struggle a lot down the line. If you want to learn NativeScript, start from basics of JavaScript, OOPS, TypeScript, then bits of iOS & Android.